# validate only when a condition is met in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a jquery validation script as follows

```
$("#form").validate({
rules:{
    type:{
        required:true
         }
      }
});
```

i want the type field to be required only when update mode is true. How can i enhance this script to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try:

```
$("#form").validate({
  rules:{
    type:{
        required:function(elem) {
           return +update_mode  > 0; //convert true/false to number and check
        }        
  }
});
```

In the code, variable `update_mode` can have either `true` or `false` value, and the code checks if `update_mode` is `true`, in which case it makes the field required for validation else not-required.